# Carbon/silicon pentacovalent intermediate during substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, molecular-orbital-theory, carbon-family

During S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction with a silicon compound, a pentacovalent intermediate is formed, while there is no such intermediate formed with carbon compounds (only a pentacovalent transition state). Why is it so? I need an MO explanation (no d orbitals involved).

Comment: Stable compounds of even 6-coordinated silicon are common. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluorosilicic_acid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bonds involving carbon are typically shorter than bonds involving silicon.  Therefore a pentacoordinated carbon species would be **sterically more crowded** around the central carbon atom than its pentacoordinated silicon analogue would be. This crowding would raise the energy of pentacoordinate carbon compared to pentacoordinate silicon; which is consistent with the observation that the S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction with carbon produces a higher energy pentacoordinate transition state, while in the case of silicon a more stable pentacoordinate intermediate can be observed.

\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
\ce{Bond} & d(\ce{X=C})/\pu{pm} & d(\ce{X=Si})/\pu{pm} \\
\hline
\ce{X-O} & 143 & 163 \\
\ce{X-Cl} & 177 & 202 \\
\ce{X-Br} & 194 & 215 \\
\ce{X-I} & 214 & 243 \\
\hline
\end{array}

**Recasting this into MO terms**, we would say that both the carbon and silicon pentacoordinate species involve a trigonal bipyramid structure where the two ligands (the "attacking" and "leaving" groups in the carbon case) occupy axial positions in the trigonal bipyramid arrangement.

[image: Structure of the SN2 transition state]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN2_reaction))

The figure above makes it easy to see that we have a [hypercoordinated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervalent_molecule) species involving a 3-center 4-electron bond. Since a silicon p-orbital is larger than a carbon p-orbital, the 4 electrons are spread out over a larger volume in the silicon case, reducing electron-electron repulsion.  This makes the pentacoordinate silicon case more stable than pentacoordinate carbon.